# Cannot install Microsoft SQL Server to Ubuntu AWS /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.30' not found

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, aws, sql, sqlserver

I am trying to install SQL server onto a Ubuntu machine on AWS and it has been nothing but trouble. I get stuck on the last step, configuring the server after selecting edition and setting an administrator password. I get this message /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.30' not found.

This is for a class, so the version of Ubuntu and the SQL server are fixed and cannot be changed. I have tried half a dozen different instances on AWS but get the same error regardless.

[image]

Comment: don't post screenshots, use cut-and-paste, because no one is going to want to have to type in any information inside those images.  what version of ubuntu? and what version of sqlserver?  Maybe you have the right version of sql server that was built for a different version of ubuntu.  Can you tell us where you got the sqlserver from?

Answer (score 0):

> This is for a class, so the version of Ubuntu and the SQL server are fixed and cannot be changed.

Unfortunately, you’ve ended up with a version of SQL Server which is incompatible with your version of Ubuntu. I imagine you’re using Ubuntu 18.04; that uses version 2.27 of the GNU C library, and your version of SQL Server needs 2.30 or later. You need to use Ubuntu 20.04 or later.

The only way to meet the requirement on 18.04 would be to manually upgrade the C library, which is highly discouraged.